# cmd "query session /server:<server_name>" returns blank on scheduled task. Why?

Tags: server, scheduled-tasks

I have a script that queries open sessions on some network based PCs using a command line bat file like this e.g

```
query session /server:<server_name> > pc1.txt
query session /server:<server_name> > pc2.txt
```

One of the lines refers to the local machine, same syntax - I user the local box server name.
When I run the bat file manually while logged in, I get the cmd output in each text file, as you would expect.  When I run the scheduled task, whether I am logged in or not, I get blank txt files  except for the local machine which is populated as expected.

I've tried `\\<server_name` and `"server_name"`, but to be honest I'm lost.

Is anyone able to get a scheduled task to report the result of `query session /server` for a remote server? If so how?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved by editing the scheduled task settings.
Storing the user credentials and running with elevated privileges made this work.